# preventing user from entering blank post in form javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular/javascript question. The code I have written works but I am wondering why as it was an educated guess I took to implement this code.

**What is the code doing?**

User enters text into the form which is then added to an array and displayed on the screen. I want to ensure that a user cannot enter a blank post. The JS code below works, but I am wondering why. I have examined the code, and thought of all the possible reasons why this would make sense, but it just doesn't. I am hoping someone can eradicate my confusion.

The code I have in my HTML is as follows:

```
<form ng-submit="addPost()">
     <input type="text" ng-model="title"></input>
     <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>

<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
     {{post}}
</div>
```

The function in my controller looks like this:

```
$scope.addPost = function(){
  if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return false}
  $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, upvotes: 0});
  $scope.title = '';
};
```

At the beginning I only had

*ORIGINAL CODE*

```
$scope.addPost = function(){
  if($scope.title === ' ') {return false}
  $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, upvotes: 0});
  $scope.title = '';
};
```

This original code makes sense to me, however with this code, the first time the user clicked submit in the input box it displayed a blank post, but on subsequent attempts it did not.

My question is why is my original code allowed a user to enter blank text on one occassion. As far as I can tell it should work the same as the code that works as it is saying if $scope.title is blank break the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add required attribute on form field that will make form as invalid

**Markup**

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && addPost(form)">
     <input type="text" ng-model="title" required/>
     <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.addPost = function(){
  $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, upvotes: 0});
  $scope.title = '';
};
```

Comment: This is coming from another angle which I appreciate but I the code I was using was already working, so wanted a bit of clarification as to why, as it was a bit of a guess that I took, but from one of the answers it now makes sense. Thanks, and have an upvote for helping :-)

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I suggested the better way of doing code..that will handle  your form validity on UI

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald if you want to implement using a cleaner solution.then you could go for my solution..all up to you..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="addPost()">
     <input type="text" ng-model="title" **required**></input>
     <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
```

Here if the text is not entered the button Submit is disabled.

Comment: As I said to the other poster the code I was using was already working, so wanted a bit of clarification as to why, as it was a bit of a guess that I took, but from one of the answers it now makes sense. But still thanks for your input as it provides another alternative

Answer (score 1):

You didnt initialized $scope.title. In your code, it doesn't exist before first function call which initialize this scope's value

```
$scope.title = '';
```

Comment: ah this makes sense. This is what was confusing me

Comment: In the same way I could actually remove the second part and just say ```if(!$scope.title){return false}``` and it also works

Comment: look @pankajparkar response, it's not answer to your question but it's better solution to achive your goal